# Take Screen shot using Listeners

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, listener

I want to take screen shot of a failed test case and add the same screen shot to the TestNG report. Pls help. I'm using below code to take screen shot:

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

        String FilePath = "C:\\Users\\test-output\\";
        new File(FilePath);  
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File( FilePath +methodName +".jpg") );
        System.out.println("***Placed screen shot in "+scrFile+" ***");
    }
```

How I can use Listeners for the same. I have created a listener class but not sure how I can use it for fail scenario.

I have added below code but how to attach the screen shot in the report using reporter.log().

```
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
    // since you need the driver in your screenshot method do this:
    this.driver = ((CNLogin)result.getInstance()).driver;
            File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            // C:\Users\499290\AppData\Local\Temp\screenshot7520341205731631960.png 
            String FilePath = "C:\\Users\\499290\\Downloads\\CNProject1\\CNProject\\test-output\\";
            new File(FilePath);  
            try {
                FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File( FilePath + ".jpg") );
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("***Placed screen shot in "+scrFile+" ***");
```

Comment: Hey @Hina: What report exactly are you talking about? There are several reports created when testNG runs with default properties... And where in the report should the Screenshot go. Here is my advice -> ask this as a new separate question and put this one back in scope with just "how to use listeners to get screenshot"

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the `ITestListener` interface, but you don't need to implement all of its methods, onTestFailure is enough, the rest can be left empty:

```
public class TestListener implements ITestListener{


    private WebDriver driver;


    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        // since you need the driver in your screenshot method do this:
        this.driver = ((TestBaseClass)result.getInstance()).driver;
        // here comes your screenshot method
        // ...
    }
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {

    }
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {

    }
    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {

    }
    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {

    }
    public void onStart(ITestContext context) {

    }
    public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {

    }
}
```

Then in your xml file just add the testlistener:

```
<suite name="allSuites">
  <suite-files>
    <suite-file path="yourtestsuite01.xml" />
    <suite-file path="yourtestsuite02.xml" />
  </suite-files>
  <listeners>
        <listener class-name="drkthng.comparex.TestListener" />
  </listeners>
</suite>
```

Then you just run the xml file as testNG.

Comment: I tried this but screen shot are not attached to the report can u pls help on this updated the question with details.

Comment: Here is the awesome step by step blog on ITestListeners. It will be helpful
https://thoughtcoders.com/blog/selenium-capture-screenshot-using-testng-itestlisteners/

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the below code in your class:

```
  public void takescreen(ITestResult result) throws IOException {
 if (!result.isSuccess()) {
 File imageFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
String failureImageFileName = result.getMethod().getMethodName()+ new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy_HH-ss").format(new GregorianCalendar().getTime())
                + ".png";
        File failureImageFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\screenshots\\"+failureImageFileName);
 FileUtils.copyFile(imageFile, failureImageFile);
    }
   }
```